# The $C^*$-algebra generated by two projections

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory, projection-matrices

The following exercise is taken from the book "An introduction to K-theory for $C^*$ algebras, exercise 13.4.

Let $A$ be the sub-$C^*$ algebra of $C([0,1],M_2(\Bbb{C}))$ consisting of all functions $f$ such that $$f(0)=\begin{pmatrix} d & 0 \\0  & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ f(1)=\begin{pmatrix} d_1 & 0 \\0  & d_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ for some $d,d_1,d_2\in \Bbb{C}$, and consider the elements $p,q\in A$ given by $$p(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0  & 0 \end{pmatrix},\ \ \ \  q(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1-t & \sqrt{t(1-t)} \\ \sqrt{t(1-t)}  & t \end{pmatrix}.$$

$(i)$ I have shown that $p,q$ are projections in $A$.

$(ii)$ Show that $A=C^*(p,q)$ by the following hints:

(a). Use $$pq(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1-t & \sqrt{t(1-t)} \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\ \ \ (p-q)^2(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t & 0\\ 0 & t \end{pmatrix}.$$

I've shown that for any $d,d_1,d_2\in \Bbb{C}$ there exists $f\in C^*(p,q)$ with $f(0)=\text{diag}(d,0)$ and $f(1)=\text{diag}(d_1,d_2)$. If it is relevant, my $f$ is given by $f=d_1p(p-q)^2+d_2(1-p)(p-q)^2+dpqp$.

Here is my problematic step:

(c). If $\{e_{i,j}\}_{i,j=1,2}$ denote the standard matrix units for $M_2(\Bbb{C})$, and $0< \delta < 1/2$, then there exists $h_{i,j}\in C^*(p,q)$ with $\|h_{i,j}\|\leq 1$ and $h_{i,j}(t)=e_{i,j}$ for $t\in [\delta, 1-\delta]$.

My idea:

Assume we can get $g(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t(1-t)  & t(1-t) \\ t(1-t) & t(1-t) \end{pmatrix} \in C^*(p,q)$, it should be possible and not very difficult, I think...

Then if I take $\min \{t(1-t), \delta(1-\delta)\}$ in each coordinate, after some normalizing,I get the desired matrix. But I couldn't find combinations that give me such a matrix (I've tried also the famous formula for minimum between two functions).

Moreover, after these steps I should conclude $(ii)$, and I'm not sure how to do it... any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps you could prove that $A = C^{\ast}(p,q)$ by using the following Stone-Weierstrass-type result (See Dixmier's *$C^{\ast}$-algebras*, Corollary 11.5.3) (Am not sure how hard it is to check though):  *Let $T$ be a locally compact space and $A$ a continuous field of $C^{\ast}$-algebras over $T$. Suppose $B$ is a sub-$C^{\ast}$-algebra of $A$ such that, for all $t_1,t_2\in T,$ and $\xi_1\in A(t_1), \xi_2\in A(t_2)$ (with $\xi_1=\xi_2$ if $t_1=t_2$), there exists $x\in B$ such that $x(t_1) = \xi_1, x(t_2) = \xi_2$. Then $B = A$*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you cannot really use $1-p$ for your $f$, since the identity is not in your subalgebra. But you can still write $(p-q)^2-p(p-q)^2$.

The idea of the hint is that by choosing $d_1$ and $d_2$ in your $f$ you can get 
$$
t\,e_{11}=\begin{bmatrix}t&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ t\,e_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&t\end{bmatrix}
$$
in $C^*(p,q)$. If you now calculate $p(p-q-te_{11}+te_{22})$ you get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&-\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in C^*(p,q).
$$
For $t\in (\delta,1-\delta)$, we can guarantee that $\sqrt{t(1-t)}>\sqrt{\delta-\delta^2}>0$.

Now, let $k\in C[0,1]$ be 
$$k(t)=\begin{cases}\dfrac t{\delta^2},&\ t\in[0,\delta]\\ \ \\ \dfrac1t,&\ t\in(\delta,1-\delta)\\ \ \\
\dfrac{1-t}{\delta(1-\delta)},&\ t\in [1-\delta,1 ]\end{cases}$$ and put $g(t)=\sqrt{k(t)\,k(1-t)}$. We get
$$
g(te_{11})=\begin{bmatrix}g(t)&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in C^*(p,q).
$$
As $g(t)\,\sqrt{t(1-t)}=1$ on $(\delta,1-\delta)$,
$$
h_{12}(t)=g(te_{11})\begin{bmatrix}0&\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in C^*(p,q)
$$
is a function such that $h_{12}(t)=e_{12}$ for $t\in(\delta,1-\delta)$, and $\|h_{12}\|\leq1$.

With a similar idea one can obtain $h_{11}$ and $h_{22}$, by doing functional calculus on $te_{11}$ and $te_{22}$ (now with $g(0)=g(1)=1$), and $h_{21}=h_{12}^*$.

So, if you now take $f\in A$, you have $$f(t)=\begin{bmatrix}f_{11}(t)&f_{12}(t)\\ f_{21}(t)&f_{22}(t)\end{bmatrix},$$
with $f_{12}(0)=f_{12}(1)=0$, $f_{21}(0)=f_{21}(1)=0$, $f_{22}(0)=0$. You have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}f_{11}(t)&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=f_{11}(te_{11})\in C^*(p,q).
$$
Similarly, $f_{22}(t)\,e_{22}=f_{22}(te_{22})\in C^*(p,q)$. We can also get $f_{12}(t)e_{11}\in C^*(p,q)$. If we now write $g_n$ for the $g$ constructed above in the case $\delta=1/n$, we get that $f_{12}=\lim_ng_nf_{12}$ (it is essential here that $f_{12}(0)=f_{12}(1)=0$ for the limit to be uniform). Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&f_{12}(t)\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}=\lim_n g_n(te_{11})f_{12}(te_{11})\,\begin{bmatrix}0&\sqrt{t(1-t)}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in C^*(p,q).
$$

Comment: I have rolled-back the edit. The point is that $g (t)\times\sqrt {t (1-t)}=1$ on $(\delta,1-\delta) $. I think that messes up the norm estimate, though, so I need to think about it.

Comment: Now I see it. The estimate needed is that $|g (t)\,\sqrt {t (1-t)}|\leq1$. And this is fine, at the cost of tweaking $\delta $ slightly (roughly), going from $\delta $ to $\sqrt\delta $).

Comment: OK, so in order to make $k$ continuous we should run from $0$ to $\sqrt{\delta}$ with $t/ \delta$ and from $\sqrt{\delta}$ to $?$ with $1/t$ and on the last segment with?

Comment: I think I have corrected it now.

Comment: I think in the definition of $g$, you want $g(t)=\sqrt{k(t)\cdot k(1-t)}$.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Edited.